# ¿Cómo sacar el número mayor en un mes( de 12) en un arreglo bidimensional? en C#

Tags: c#

Esto es mi código, necesito ayuda por que a la hora de compilar me da error, me aparece 4 veces lo mismo y solo debe que aparecer una vez

```
for (int fila = 0; fila < ventasSemanales2020.GetLength(0); fila++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"MAYOR DEL MES DE {nombreMeses[fila].ToUpper()}:");
    for (int columna = 0; columna < ventasSemanales2020.GetLength(1); columna++)
    {
        double mayor = -1;
        double NumeroSemana = columna;
        if (ventasSemanales2020[fila, columna] >= mayor)
        {
            mayor = ventasSemanales2020[fila, columna];
        }
     Console.WriteLine($"El ingreso mayor es: {mayor} en la semana {NumeroSemana+1}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Recuerda que tienes el mensaje de mayor de la semana dentro del for por lo tanto se repetirá el numero de veces la cantidad de datos, en tu arreglo... veo que comparas las columnas para determinar el mayor entre ellas, por lo tanto tu ultimo consolo writeLine tiene que estar fuera del segundo for... por lo tanto la variable mayor y NumeroSemana tienes que declararla al antes de ese segundo for...

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener el mayor de cada fila debes corregir el código a lo siguiente:

```
for (int fila = 0; fila < ventasSemanales2020.GetLength(0); fila++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"MAYOR DEL MES DE {nombreMeses[fila].ToUpper()}:");
                        double mayor = -1;
                        double NumeroSemana = 0;
                        for (int columna = 0; columna < ventasSemanales2020.GetLength(1); columna++)
                        {
                            if (ventasSemanales2020[fila, columna] >= mayor)
                            {
                                mayor = ventasSemanales2020[fila, columna];
                                NumeroSemana=columna;
                            }
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine($"El ingreso mayor es: {mayor} en la semana {NumeroSemana+1}");
                    }
```

Comment: haha Justo como decía... bien hecho amigo, espero le funcione a él

Comment: :) cierto, no había leído tu comentario @CarlosDuarte